# Curl not working on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, instagram

```
    <?php 
$userid = "USER_ID";
$accessToken = "EXAMPLE_TOKEN";
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
$result = json_decode($result);

 foreach ($result->data as $post)
 {
  echo '<p>  <a class="fancybox" href="'.$post->images->standard_resolution->url.'" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="'.$post->caption->text.'"><img src="'.$post->images->thumbnail->url.'" alt="SOME TEXT HERE"></p>';
 }
     ?>
```

id like to use this working code so i can populate a div but its not working on wordpress.

Comment: Unfortunately `not working` isn't going to help us help you. Have you checked your error logs or the result of `curl_error()`, whats `not working`?

Comment: Warning: you should remove your `$accessToken` (or blank it out) from the question text, someone could violate your account!

Comment: I've also hidden the USER_ID. As @LozCherone is suggesting, show us more info, especially logs. When you run this code, are there any errors?

Comment: Im using a online compiler to make it work http://www.compileonline.com/.

Here is my error PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/vintanna_themev11/index.php on line 147

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling a `HTTPs` URL , you need to enable this parameter..

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

By setting this paramater to FALSE prevents cURL from verifying the peer's certificate